# Using array to give textboxes text through a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a login system where people can create a user, and modify their profile. The page where they can modify their profile, consist of textboxes where either their current profile data is loaded in, or a default value is assigned for the textbox. Right now i fill the textboxes by hardcoding the text inside it. I would like to do that with a loop instead, to reduce the lines of code.

I have tried to put the textboxes themselves in an array and set up a loop where each arrayindex is equal to the value of an other array. That obviously does not work because the array with the textboxes just get overwritten with the other array with the values. Something abit similar have worked for me in an other context though.

Here is the hardcoded example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
            string UserID = Session["LoggedInUserID"].ToString();
            SqlConnection LoadProfileConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand LoadProfileCmd = new SqlCommand();
            LoadProfileCmd.Connection = LoadProfileConnection;
            LoadProfileCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            LoadProfileCmd.CommandText = "LoadProfileRediger";
            LoadProfileCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", UserID);
            LoadProfileConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader ReadProfileData = LoadProfileCmd.ExecuteReader();
            RedigerPassTxt.Text = ReadProfileData["Pass"].ToString();
            RedigerEmailTxt.Text = ReadProfileData["Email"].ToString();
            RedigerVirksomhedTxt.Text = ReadProfileData["Virksomhed"].ToString();
            RedigerFornavnTxt.Text = ReadProfileData["Fornavn"].ToString();
            RedigerEfternavnTxt.Text = ReadProfileData["Efternavn"].ToString();
            RedigerAdresseTxt.Text = ReadProfileData["Adresse"].ToString();
            RedigerTelefonTxt.Text = ReadProfileData["Telefon"].ToString();
            ReadProfileData.Close();
            LoadProfileConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Here is the failed attempt. I have tried it where it wasnt in an external
function. That obviously did not help:

```
        public void TextboxViewQuery(string con, string proc, string[] inputs, string[] vars, string paraSqlVar, string paraVar) 
        {
            SqlConnection LoadProfileConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[con].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand LoadProfileCmd = new SqlCommand();
            LoadProfileCmd.Connection = LoadProfileConnection;
            LoadProfileCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            LoadProfileCmd.CommandText = proc;
            LoadProfileCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paraSqlVar, paraVar);
            LoadProfileConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader ReadProfileData = LoadProfileCmd.ExecuteReader();
            ReadProfileData.Read();
            for (int i = 0; i < vars.Length; i++)
            {
                inputs[i] = ReadProfileData[vars[i]].ToString();
            }
            ReadProfileData.Close();
            LoadProfileConnection.Close();
       }
```

The expected result was to get text into the textboxes dynamically. Though i do understand why it does not work as it is now. There are no error messages.

Comment: "I have tried to put the textboxes themselves in an array" ...have you? I see no array of textboxes in your failed attempt, only some arrays of strings. It's unclear from that how you propose to get the values back into the textboxes. if you did actually put the textboxes into an array, then please show that version. What you want should be possible. e.g. if `inputs` was actually an array of textboxes instead of strings, then `inputs[i].Text = ReadProfileData[vars[i]].ToString();` woudl probably do what you wanted.

Comment: Try inputs[i].Text = ReadProfileData[vars[i]].ToString().Trim();

Comment: Hey thank you guys, i made an array of textbox type, and it worked. As you can probably tell im sort of a beginner.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear ADyson. In the failed attempt example, the "string[] inputs" parameter was the array with textboxes. So as you say,i need to make it and array of textbox datatype and not string. Did not know that was possible.

Comment: You can make an array of absolutely any type you like :-)